# Angular Routing Pretty URL Error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to make angular routing application. here is my code.

```
<html ng-app="LumenApp">
<head>
    <title>LumanAngular v1.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" ng-view>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
```

Angular Scripts..

```
var app = angular.module('LumenApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });


});


// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

app.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

app.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

home.html

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>
{{message}}
```

about.html

```
<h1>About Page</h1>
{{message}}
```

contact.html

```
<h1>Contact Page</h1>
{{message}}
```

No wthis contiton its working perfectly and injecting the home.html, about.html and contact.html into the template.

But I want to remove the hash(#) tag from the url as next.

I searched a lot and get the solution like that to add the below code in routing configuration function.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
            requireBase: false,
            enabled: true
        });
```

After that the hash tag was removed, but the injection of pages to template is not working..

Why this happen like this. when I removed the above location code, its working perfectly as I already explained.

How can I fix this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Apache server for hosting your app, add a `.htaccess` file in your root folder:

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /restapi/app/ 

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

And add a `base` tag in your index.html file `head`:

```
<base href="/restapi/app/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To use this you need an express js backend to serve the basic index page with Angular script dependencies

It comes with every request so that your app knows how to route.

Create a route that sends the index on every request if no other route is sent.